# Fetch specific order having created in last 24 hours using mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am stuck in a query where I need to fetch the orders which has no invoice and time of creation has increased from 24 hours.

`orders = company.orders.where(invoice_id: nil).where(:created_at.gte => (Time.now - 1.day))`

Comment: is this mongoid?

Comment: yes it is mongoid

Answer (score 0):

May be that works for someone else
I was mistaken in .gte but I need to add .lte

```
orders = company.orders.where(invoice_id: nil).where(:created_at.lte => (Time.now - 1.day))
```